# Redux-toolkit: Store does not have a valid reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I am completely lost on redux and next.js. I can't seem to figure out how to just simply connect the two after many frustrating hours. My site returns an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined". For some reason the store doesn't seem to have a valid reducer.

The following is the code that seems to be the problem.
_app.js

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import store from "../store";
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from "react-redux";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }) {
  return (
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <SessionProvider session={session}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </SessionProvider>
    </ReduxProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import counterReducer from "./slices/counterSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { counter: counterReducer },
});
```

counterSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  value: 0,
};

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.value += 1;
    },

    decrement: (state) => {
      state.value -= 1;
    },

    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions;
export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

all I am looking for is the site to not break. I just want to be able to play around with global state to change one variable from true to false and vice versa across different components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `store` is `undefined` because it's not being imported correctly. Right now it's being exported from `store.js` as a [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#description) (not `default`), so during import you'll need to remember to use curly braces:

**_app.js**:

```js
// don't forget the curly braces around `store`
import { store } from "../store";
```

Alternatively, if your intention is to import the `default` (so you can use a name other than `store`), remember to specify the `store` module's `default` export:

**store.js**:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { counter: counterReducer },
});

// `store` can be named something else during import (and no curly braces needed)
export default store;
```

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick. Quite frustrated it was such a simple mistake. You're the man.